# Create a drop down list without impacting the HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have tried to create a drop-down list, but the list doesn't look good and when opening, it keeps changing the size of the HStack

```
ZStack {
                VStack() {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(filters[selectedFilter].name)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .none))
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45.0))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(Animation.spring().speed(2)) {
                                showOptions.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if showOptions {
                            VStack() {
                                ForEach(filters.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                                    Text(filters[i].name)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            showOptions.toggle()
                                            selectedFilter = i
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45.0))
                        }
```

I posted some pics of the result when collapsed

[image]

below when expanded

[image]

I do not want the dropdown on the right side but below. Also as you can see, the entire icons are moving down. I need the icons to stay on top and just have a simple dropdown when clicking on the text on the left

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: How about using a `Menu` instead. That's a "dropdown list".

Comment: Or a `Picker` with the `.menu` style if this is a picker.

Answer (score 0):

The other buttons move downwards because the `HStack`'s alignment is `.center`.

If you set the alignment to `.top`, the other buttons will not move downwards:

```
@State var showingDropdown = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            (Text("Surf ") + Text(Image(systemName: "chevron.right")))
                .padding()
                .background(.thinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        showingDropdown.toggle()
                    }
                }
            if showingDropdown {
                VStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                        Text(option)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.thinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(30)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

If you want the dropdown to appear directly below "Surf >", wrap them both in a `VStack(alignment: .leading)`. Again, the alignment matters here.

That said, the easier way to make a dropdown is with a `Menu`:

```
let options = ["option1", "option2", "foo", "bar", "baz", "something else"]
```

```
Menu {
    ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
        Button(option) {
            // ...
        }
    }
} label: {
    (Text("Surf ") + Text(Image(systemName: "chevron.right")))
}
.padding()
.background(.thinMaterial)
.cornerRadius(30)
```

Since this looks like a picker, also consider using a `Picker` with a style of `.menu`:

```
@State var pickedOption = "option1"
```

```
Picker("Some Picker", selection: $pickedOption) {
    ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
        Text(option)
    }
}
.padding()
.background(.thinMaterial)
.cornerRadius(30)
.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom preference key.

```
struct BoundsPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [Anchor<CGRect>] = [] 
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [Anchor<CGRect>], nextValue: () -> [Anchor<CGRect>]) {
        value.append(contentsOf:nextValue())
    }
}
```

Then add anchor preference key to the view you want. In current case the `Surf Button`

```
(Text("Surf ") + Text(Image(systemName: "chevron.right")))
                .padding()
                .background(.thinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .anchorPreference(key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self, //anchor preference  
                                      value: .bounds) { [$0] }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        showingDropdown.toggle()
                    }
                }
```

and finally add an overlayPreferenceValue to your VStack

```
 VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            (Text("Surf ") + Text(Image(systemName: "chevron.right")))
                .padding()
                .background(.thinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        showingDropdown.toggle()
                    }
                }
           
        }
        .padding()
        Spacer()
    }
    .overlayPreferenceValue(BoundsPreferenceKey.self) { // Add this 
            pref in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                if showingDropdown { // flag to make it conditional otherwise this will be visible 
                    pref.map{
                        
                        YourMenuView // Replace this with your view for the menu
                            .offset(x: geometry[$0].minX,
                                    y: geometry[$0].minY + (geometry[$0].height + 8)) // replace 8 with any number you want this will act as padding
                        
                    }[0]
                } else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
            }
    }
```

[image]